# Why do we have $\mu_* \mathcal{O}_Y(K_{Y/X}) = \mathcal{O}_X$ for a resolution?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, divisors-algebraic-geometry, line-bundles

Let $X$ be a normal complex variety and $\mu : Y \to X$ a resolution of singularities. We define the relative canonical divisor to be $K_{Y/X} := K_Y - \mu^* K_X$.

In his book Positivity in Algebraic Geometry II, Lazarsfeld mentions in passing (pg.146) that $\mu_* \mathcal{O}_Y(K_{Y/X})  = \mathcal{O}_X$. Why is this true?

Comment: Hint: normality. I'll come back later when I've got a bit more time and write a real answer if nobody's done so by then.

Comment: @KReiser Thanks for your help.